# Python Keras - CNN stuck on epoch 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
from keras import *
import os
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras import optimizers
#from parser import load_data # data loading

# Collecting data:
img_width, img_height = 150, 150
training_data_dir = "train"
testing_data_dir = "test"

# used to rescale the pixel values from [0, 255] to [0, 1] interval
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# automagically retrieve images and their classes for train and validation sets
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        training_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=16,
        class_mode='binary')

test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        testing_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

# Building model:
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(img_width, img_height,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer="rmsprop",
              metrics=["accuracy"])

#  Training model:
nb_epoch = 30
nb_train_samples = 2048
nb_validation_samples = 832

model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        samples_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
        nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
        validation_data=test_generator,
        nb_val_samples=nb_validation_samples)
```

This is my code for a CNN which is trained using images from the folders train and test. But whenever I try training it, the program seems to get stuck at epoch 1/30 all the time, i left it on overnight for 8 hours and it hasn't moved along at all, any fixes I could try?

## Update:

The output of my code currently is:

Using TensorFlow backend.
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
image_classifiy.py:78: UserWarning: Update your `fit_generator` call to the Keras 2 API: `fit_generator(<keras_pre..., epochs=30, validation_data=<keras_pre..., validation_steps=832, steps_per_epoch=128)`
steps_per_epoch=128)
Epoch 1/30

Comment: Does it show "Epoch 1/max_epochs" and nothing more? then either your data does not arrive or you run out of memory silently. You can test your generators with next(train_generator) and look if it returns something

Comment: I updated my post with the output ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By decoding  "Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes", one can conclude that the subdirectories for each class are not created. In keras, there must be a folder for every class and in that folder it must contain the images. So, make sure you make subdirectories for each class inside the train and test folders.